# processing several big csv in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, match, bigdata

I am working on two big datasets (one with 1 million records and 6 features, and the another is around 7000 records with 9 features ) .  I have used dictionary to read the data and no problem but the main idea that for every record from (1000000 records) I need to find the matching record from the another csv file...(including several if..else statements) .. and every time I should return to the beginning of the file to search for the matched rule.
This took several days and still process around 200 000 only after 5 days..

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader1:
        Find_Match(row)


def Find_Match(row):
    matches = []
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[2]))
    for k in reader2:
        if (several kind of statement for matching like is row[0] is eaual to k[0] and row[1] is in k[1]..and so on)
        else:
        print "no match"
        matches.append(row, k)
```

Comment: Why not to read the second file once and reuse in the Find_Match function?

Comment: If I read it once , I need to return the pointer to the beginning of the (reader2) file (by seek(0)) , it can be done but the same slow

Comment: I mean reading into a some python struct, then use it inside the function.

Comment: If you sort the dictionaries on the keys then you won't have to return to the beginning of the dict for each find operation. You just need to keep track of where you are in the second dict, which you can do via a variable. Also. Remove the print if speed is an issue.

Comment: have you tried using pandas and doing a join? Your join conditions are a bit vague to know for sure but if they are just `=` or `in` then you will probably be in luck with a small amount of etl

Comment: @ Alexander Volkovsky  I will try such a solution

Comment: @ William Pearsall  ,  if I understand correctly, I can keep track where I am ( in the second file reader2 for searching for the matching rule) after the soritng,.. I will try it thank you

Comment: @Matt I will try it to see how is going,, and I will update answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it still is slow after running everything in memory (as @Alexander suggested). Another idea, but depends on the data would be: Maybe you can try to exit the second loop early, e.g. create a Set/Dictionary of the values in one of the columns, sth like:

```py
col0 = {k[0] for k in dataset2}
def Find_Match(row):
  for k in dataset2:
    if not row[0] in col0:
      continue
    #...
```